# How to traverse an iterator of Text values twice in a Mapreduce program?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In my MapReduce program, I have a reducer function which counts the number of items in a Iterator of Text values and then for each item in the iterator outputs the item as key and the count as value. Thus i need to use the iterator twice. But once the iterator has reached the end I cannot get to iterate from the first. How do i solve this problem?
I tried the following code for my reduce function:

```
   public static class ReduceA extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text>output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {
            Text t;
            int count =0;                
            String[] attr = key.toString().split(",");      

           while(values.hasNext())               
            {
                values.next();
                count++;

            }

           //Maybe i need to reset my iterator here and start from the beginning but how do i do it?

           String v=Integer.toString(count);
           while(values.hasNext())               
            {
                t=values.next();

                output.collect(t,new Text(v));
            }
        }  
      }
```

The above code produced empty results.I had tried by inserting the values of the iterator in a list but since I need to deal with many GBs of data,I am getting java heap space error for using the list. Please help me to modify my code so that I can traverse the iterator twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do it the simple way : declare a List and cache the value as you iterate through the first time. You could consequently iterate through your List and write out your output. You should have something similar to this :

```
public static class ReduceA extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
    Text t;
    int count = 0;
    String[] attr = key.toString().split(",");
    List<Text> cache = new ArrayList<Text>();

    while (values.hasNext()) {
        cache.add(values.next());
        count++;

    }

    // Maybe i need to reset my iterator here and start from the beginning
    // but how do i do it?

    String v = Integer.toString(count);
    for (Text text : cache) {
        output.collect(text, new Text(v));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Caching all the values coming under a key in a list is not a preferred way to do this job.If a single key has huge number of values then the Java list may not be able to hold all these values in heap.This can result in `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception.

Comment: @donut You're right, the solution is only possible if the heap can contain all the values. But there is visibly no other way other than outputing `key => value` and `key => {SPECIAL_PREFIX}_count` and running a second job that will retrieve, process and output in the desired format.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.I just mentioned the potential risk of taking cache in the list.

Comment: @blazy: I already used a list for caching and I got the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception . Plz suggest me some other way of doing this.

Comment: @blazy: I did not understand this line " But there is visibly no other way other than outputing key => value and key => {SPECIAL_PREFIX}_count and running a second job that will retrieve, process and output in the desired format. ".. Would you kindly explain ?

Comment: @Monami My suggestion is that you add a second MapReduce job.Your 1st job outputs the `Key => Value` alongside the count for each key in a way that the counts arrive first to the Reducer in your 2nd job `(ex : "."+Key => Count)` thanks to the sorting phase.Your 2nd Mapper only forwards the input to the Reducer.Since the counts are guaranteed to arrive first to the Reducer, it stores them in a _Map_.Consequently, as the other rows arrive,you directly output `Value=>Count` based on the key as stored in the _Map_. **Note that only one Reducer should be used in the 2nd MapReduce for this to work**

Comment: @blazy: The details of the problem and full program is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042829/getting-java-heap-space-error-while-running-a-mapreduce-code-for-large-dataset?noredirect=1#comment35327270_23042829 . I am sorry I still cannot follow ur suggestion. Mayb if u talk in reference to the actual program I will find it easier

Comment: @MonamiSen I just elaborated my proposition there based on the full problem.